# Most elegant way to define helper variable in one-line expression

Tags: python, syntactic-sugar

What's the best way to define a helper variable in a one-line expression in Python?  I've found two: list comprehension and the "walrus" operator, but both can be somewhat clunky.

**Example**:

Suppose I want to create a one-line lambda sort function to sort dates from US date format into chronological order.   I'm going to split the string into a 3-tuple consisting of month-date-year, store that tuple in a helper variable `mdy`, and then use the elements of the tuple as keys in the sort.

I could do this using list comprehension:

```
bash-3.2$ python3
>>> usdates=["2/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "12/31/2021"]
>>> f = lambda x: [(mdy[2], mdy[0], mdy[1]) for mdy in [x.split("/")]][0] 
>>> sorted(usdates, key=f)
['12/31/2021', '1/2/2022', '2/1/2022']
```

or by using the "walrus" operator inside an "if" clause:

```
bash-3.2$ python3
>>> usdates=["2/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "12/31/2021"]
>>> f = lambda x: (mdy[2], mdy[0], mdy[1]) if (mdy:=x.split("/")) else "ERROR!"
>>> sorted(usdates, key=f)
['12/31/2021', '1/2/2022', '2/1/2022']
```

Both methods are somewhat clunky. List comprehension requires unwrapping of a single-element list.  But the walrus operator can be used only in an "if" or similar clause, which in turn requires an "else" statement.

What I'm really looking for is something like this:

```
bash-3.2$ python3
>>> f = lambda x: with x.split("/") as mdy: (mdy[2], mdy[0], mdy[1])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f = lambda x: with x.split("/") as mdy: (mdy[2], mdy[0], mdy[1])
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Is there any way to do something like this in Python 3?  Thanks!

EDIT:  In response to the comments so far saying "don't do this!" -- I understand that this may not be the most idiomatic way to use Python, but I'm interested in finding ways to perform custom sorting that can be easily called from the command-line, perhaps in a pipeline with shell commands.

My main question is whether Python has any better "syntactic sugar" than what I've already found. If the answer's "no", that's fine. Cheers!

Comment: There's no prize for fitting everything into a one-liner. If it's clunky, just don't try to do it. Define a named function and call that.

Comment: Agree with @Barmar. What you want (the version with `with` operator) looks pretty unreadable.

Comment: Beware of lexical comparisons when dealing with dates. If the date format is YYYYMMDD then you can compare lexically - otherwise you may get surprising results

Answer (score 3):

> But the walrus operator can be used only in an "if" or similar clause, which in turn **requires an "else" statement**

Not really...

```
lambda x: [mdy := x.split("/")] and (mdy[2], mdy[0], mdy[1])
```

The list comp allows nicer variable names, btw:

```
lambda x: [(y, m, d) for m, d, y in [x.split("/")]][0]
```

Or with a function:

```
lambda x: (lambda m, d, y: (y, m, d))(*x.split("/"))
```

Comment: This works for the given data but is not a general solution. Consider: usdates=["2/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "12/20/2022"]. This is because the sort is doing lexical comparisons which won't always work for dates. This can be resolved by converting *y*, *m* & *d* to *int*

Comment: @ArthurKing True, but that's what the question did. I suggest you comment there instead. But last two can handle that with additional `map(int, ...)`, first one is more annoying. Or just `int(...)` them individually.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) method to fetch and reorder the date parts

```
from operator import itemgetter
usdates = ["2/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "12/31/2021"]
f = lambda x: itemgetter(2, 0, 1)(x.split('/'))
sorted(usdates, key=f)
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply!  That function is very useful in the particular example I gave in the question, and indeed could be useful for many multi-key sort problems, which was my main motivation for posting here.  I'm still curious as to my general question about helper variables, but think that this function will take care of many of the cases in which I would want to use it in practice.

Comment: This works for the given data but is not a general solution. Consider: usdates=["2/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "12/20/2022"]. This is because the sort is doing lexical comparisons which won't always work for dates

Answer (score 0):

If your dealing with dates, why not treat them a dates?

```py
from dateutil import parser
usdates=["2/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "12/31/2021"]

print(sorted(usdates, key=parser.parse))
```

```
['12/31/2021', '1/2/2022', '2/1/2022']
```

Comment: If you're having a function, why not treat it as a function? :-P `key=parser.parse`

Comment: You might think the lambda really tied the room together, but, well, you know, that’s just, like, your opinion, man. Python doesn't need it.

Comment: The dude abides!  100% not needed. #Silence of the Lambdas

Comment: Worth mentioning that parser.parse defaults to the American format. Thus, as written, *dayfirst* is False